# Finding shapes using OpenCV Haar cascaded classifier

Tags: image-processing, opencv, object-recognition

I am looking for parabolas in some radar data. I am using the OpenCV Haar cascaded classifier. My positive images are 20x20 PNGs where all of the pixels are black, except for those that trace a parabolic shape--one parabola per positive image.

My question is this: will these positives train a classifier to look for black boxes with parabolas in them, or will they train a classifier to look for parabolic shapes?

Should I add a layer of medium value noise to my positive images, or should they be unrealistically crisp and high contrast?

Here is an example of the original data.

[image: The original data.]

Here is an example of my data after I have performed simple edge detection using GIMP. The parabolic shapes are highlighted in the white boxes

[image: Data after edge detection.]

Here is one of my positive images.

[image: A sample positive image.]

Comment: Post some photos. It will really help to get good answers.

Comment: But a fast answer would be that you don't need something so complicated as Haar for some parabolas.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response @vasile. The Haar training **is** taking a very long time to complete. What do you recommend for detecting parabolas?

Comment: What do you want to detect here? The column indexes where the horizontal lines are interrupted? or the peaks? Can you make a red line around the feature you want to detect? You also say this pic is processed in Gimp. Would be good to see the original, also. Haar does not seem to be of much help here, but it is a very interesting problem

Comment: There are very (very) faint parabolic signatures. In the original data, the green image, there is a faint parabola under the red and blue lines, around 147 ft. (The tick marks are in tens of feet.) Again, if Haar is not an optimal choice, do you have other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to do detect parabolas initially using the MatchTemplate method from OpenCV. At first, I was using the Python `cv`, and later `cv2` libraries, but I had to make sure that my input images were 8-bit unsigned integer arrays. I eventually obtained a similar effect with less fuss using `scipy.signal.correlate2d( image, template, mode='same')`. The `mode='same'` resizes the output to the size of `image`. When I was done I performed thresholding, using the `numpy.where()` function, and opening and closing to eliminate salt and pepper noise using the `scipy.ndimage` module.

Here's the output, before thresholding.

[image]